# Override wordpress audio playlist

Tags: filters, shortcode, audio

To overwrite wordpress audio you would use wp_audio_shortcode_override filter and then return your own output.

Is there a way to overwrite audio playlist?

```
[playlist ids="1268,1265,1196"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortcode you can use to override playlist shortcode I guess: `wp_playlist_shortcode()`

Link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_playlist_shortcode/

Comment: But how can one intercept all such shortcodes to build its own ouput?

Comment: You can use the [`post_playlist`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_playlist/) filter to create your own output.

Comment: Can you provide little more info or maybe similar example? When could I run such filter in wordpress?